# Fibonacci sequence in SML

Tags: sml

```
  1 fun fib 0 = 0                                                                   
  2     | fib 1 = 1                                                                 
  3     | fib n = (fib n-1) + (fib n-2)                                             
  4                                                                                 
  5 val x = fib 8
```

What's incorrect about this implementation of the nth number in the fibonacci sequence? When I run the program it just hangs...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`fib n - 1` is equivalent to `(fib n) - 1`, not `fib (n - 1)`. So the line `fib n = (fib n - 1) + (fib n - 2)` calls `fib n` again, causing infinite recursion.

To fix the problem, add parentheses.